# How to get my iPhone-only app to look correct on the iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have created an app that is designed for iPhone only. You are required by apple to have your iPhone app fit the iPad in 2x mode, but I cannot figure out how to do this. I thought that it was suppose to automatically double the screen size (but not the resolution) on the iPad, but that is clearly not the case. Here is what it looks like on an iPhone 7:

[image: iPhone7]

What it looks like on iPad Air 2 2x mode:

[image: iPad]

How can I make it so that it fits perfectly in this 2x mode? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you can get your app to work correctly on a 3.5" iPhone (such as the iPhone 4), then it will look correct on an iPad.

Comment: Ah, so that it is the iPhone 4 that correlates to the iPad. Thanks, that is very helpful.